# Preventing variables in SQL generated from EF Core (SQL Server)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

The question is how would one go about removing 'DECLARE ' statements that are generated by EF Core when doing a select query with filters.

**Reasoning and Story**

SQL Server seems to have some issues with queries that contain filters which are variables.
For instance the first query below runs slower than the second one (for our case):

```
DECLARE @RegionId INT = 1;

SELECT * FROM [Customers] WHERE RegionId=@RegionId
```

*Query 1 - Variables*

```
SELECT * FROM [Customers] WHERE RegionId=1
```

*Query 2 - Constants*

We've looked for possible causes for this problem at the SQL Server, but weren't able to find anything useful yet (like a real solution). At the EF Core end of things, we've tried to come up with a command interceptor, but it seems like the intercepted commandtext doesn't come with variable statements included, not sure at which point they are added to the actual sql string.

One non-ideal solution for us would be to use Raw SQL queries, but even those when used with EF Core's parametization system (for anti-injection purposes) uses variables. So we have to give up using parameterization and hand-code the parameters. This means we have to somehow encode parameter values to prevent injection attacks. Another problem with using Raw SQL queries for our case is, almost all of our SELECT queries are backed/built by AutoMapper's ProjectTo extension, so it makes extra joins (inner query is raw, outer query is generated by AutoMapper's ProjectTo).

**UPDATE**

After reading comments, I gathered execution plans for the two different scenarios we encounter.

Scenario 1 - with variables:

```sql
-- Query 1, with variables
DECLARE @__p_1 int = 10;
DECLARE @__organizationId_0 int = 123; -- Some number

SELECT 
  TOP(@__p_1) [c0].[Id] AS [CustomerContactId], 
  [c0].[CustomerId], 
  -- Other Columns...
  [c].[PermitDate] 
FROM 
  [ContactActivationHistory] AS [c] 
  INNER JOIN [CustomerContact] AS [c0] ON [c].[CustomerContactId] = [c0].[Id] 
  INNER JOIN [Customer] AS [c1] ON [c0].[CustomerId] = [c1].[Id] 
WHERE 
  (
    ([c].[OrganizationId] = __organizationId_0) 
    AND ([c0].[StatusId] = 1)
  ) 
  AND ([c1].[StatusId] = 1) 
ORDER BY 
  [c].[PermitDate] DESC
```

Execution plan for this query (XML):

https://gist.github.com/ahmetcanturker/79de974ec27c92d9cbd9c97bca3b474b

---

Scenario 2 - with paging variable only:

```sql
-- Query 2, with paging variable only
DECLARE @__p_1 int = 10;

SELECT 
  TOP(@__p_1) [c0].[Id] AS [CustomerContactId], 
  [c0].[CustomerId], 
  -- Other Columns
  [c].[PermitDate] 
FROM 
  [ContactActivationHistory] AS [c] 
  INNER JOIN [CustomerContact] AS [c0] ON [c].[CustomerContactId] = [c0].[Id] 
  INNER JOIN [Customer] AS [c1] ON [c0].[CustomerId] = [c1].[Id] 
WHERE 
  (
    ([c].[OrganizationId] = 123)  -- Same number as query 1
    AND ([c0].[StatusId] = 1)
  ) 
  AND ([c1].[StatusId] = 1) 
ORDER BY 
  [c].[PermitDate] DESC
```

Execution plan for this query (XML):

https://gist.github.com/ahmetcanturker/e8654feb5a0e346a14377402eead1d09

**Extra info**

Tables used:

**ContactActivationHistory**

Columns

- Id
- OrganizationId
- CustomerContactId
- ...
- PermitDate (datetime)

Indexes

- PK (Id, Clustered)
- CustomerContactId (Non-Unique, Non-Clustered)
- OrganizationId (Non-Unique, Non-Clustered)
- PermitDate (Non-Unique, Non-Clustered)
- IsPermit (Non-Unique, Non-Clustered)

**CustomerContact**

Columns

- Id
- OrganizationId
- CustomerId
- ...
- StatusId

Indexes

- PK (Id, Clustered)
- OrganizationId (Non-Unique, Non-Clustered)
- CustomerId (Non-Unique, Non-Clustered)
- StatusId (Non-Unique, Non-Clustered)

**Customer**

Columns

- Id
- OrganizationId
- ...
- StatusId

Indexes

- PK (Id, Clustered)
- (OrganizationId, StatusId) (Non-Unique, Non-Clustered)

Extra Note:

We run index rebuild jobs on the SQL Server, and even with those, we get high fragmentation numbers fairly quickly. These tables get a lot of inserts.

Comment: Are these just relatively simple selects? If you're joining a few different tables, it might be worthwhile to do it as a stored procedure. Or do you not have access to the underlying DB?

Comment: Really it should not be notifiable difference. Maybe your query does too much work. What are the difference in execution plan when you execute query with and without variable?

Comment: You can intercept LINQ query and precisely translate member access expressions to constants.  Check `ParameterExtractingExpressionVisitor.cs` in EF Core sources and especially `EvaluatableExpressionFindingExpressionVisitor`. Also, probably simplest way is to replace `IEvaluatableExpressionFilter` for your DbContext.

Comment: Because you've mentioned looking for the cause for a difference in performance, it's because of [Cardinality Estimation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/cardinality-estimation-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15). DECLARE parameters means the value is unknown upon query compilation. So the DB engine estimation for indexes/statistics is a guess instead of knowing it accurately. (this is especially true when using a parameter on an indexed column). On more complex queries or large volumes of data this can lead to performance 'problems'.

Comment: If the variables are the result of passing parameters in the `ProjectTo` call, you can try using the `Dictionary` overload. That will generate constants instead of parameters.

Comment: @AndrewCorrigan We are trying to keep it as much EF/code first/all as possible. The reason we do not use SP's etc. is when our select model changes we need to update the db instance(s) with multiple deployments at customer ends, it becomes harder and harder to perform db tasks. Of course we could create/update the sp from EF side (I suppose it would work similar to migrating/seeding data at startup, etc.). Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @AdamJachocki Well the actual time it takes to select the results is quite different. I should also add that, the difference gets very large when there is no data to select (order by, take X sort of stuff). When performing a no data select, variables seem to make sql not able "know" that there is no data or something. We should analyze the execution plans and compare though, haven't done that yet. Thanks.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Definetely going to check those files, thanks for the direction.

Comment: @DKramer Well the problems around this are explained in detail in a lot of places, but sometimes the solution is very unclear. For this case, EF Core automatically generates variables, and doesn't seem to have a built-in way to use constant values instead. I would actually prefer to use constant values unless I have a very specific reason not to, but we use EF here so...

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I don't think we pass any parameters to the ProjectTo calls (except for the mapping configuration provider), but I will check if we get parameters with/without ProjectTo the sameway. Thanks.

Comment: It generates parameters, and usually to parameter transferred evaluatable expression (Method call, Member Access, Condition, etc.)

Comment: Without seeing execution plans and indexes we can't really help much. It sounds like a parameter sniffing problem to be honest

Comment: You likely have a parameter sniffing issue.  To confirm, look at the query plans for the various cases (either use the query store or use set statistics profile on to see the plans for each case).  With the query store you can force a plan for the parameterized case if there is one that performs better most of the time for your workload. dbcc freeproccache can help reset state between experiments

Comment: Agree that parameter sniffing is a good avenue to explore. But sometimes it can be difficult to find the right solution

Comment: Not sure if any of those helps but, updated the question with some details you guys have mentioned.